# Can I get the return value of Shell.Application's ShellExecute?

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I'm using VBScript to create a UAC prompt for a batch file. I don't know how to get the return value of the UAC prompt. For example if I try to UAC a file that doesn't exist I should get an error, right?

For example:

```
Dim rc
Set UAC = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
rc = UAC.ShellExecute("thisdoesntexist.exe", "", "", "runas", 1)
WScript.Echo rc
```

rc doesn't contain a code. Also, is there any way I can get the error code of whatever I'm executing? Is ShellExecute asynchronous in VBScript?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### **[IShellDispatch2.ShellExecute method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**
>
> Performs a specified operation on a specified file.
>
> Syntax
>
> IShellDispatch2.ShellExecute(sFile [, vArguments] [, vDirectory] [,
>   vOperation] [, vShow]) Parameters
>
> sFile Required. String that contains the name of the file on which
>   ShellExecute will perform the action specified by vOperation.
>
> vArguments Optional. Variant that contains the parameter values for
>   the operation.
>
> vDirectory Optional. Variant that contains the fully qualified path of
>   the directory that contains the file specified by sFile. If this
>   parameter is not specified, the current working directory is used.
>
> vOperation Optional. Variant that specifies the operation to be
>   performed. It should be set to one of the verb strings that is
>   supported by the file. For a discussion of verbs, see the Remarks
>   section. If this parameter is not specified, the default operation is
>   performed.
>
> vShow Optional. Variant that recommends how the window that belongs to
>   the application that performs the operation should be displayed
>   initially. The application can ignore this recommendation. vShow can
>   take one of the following values. If this parameter is not specified,
>   the application uses its default value.0
>
> Open the application with a hidden window.
>
> 1 Open the application with a normal window. If the window is
>   minimized or maximized, the system restores it to its original size
>   and position.
>
> 2 Open the application with a minimized window.
>
> 3 Open the application with a maximized window.
>
> 4 Open the application with its window at its most recent size and
>   position. The active window remains active.
>
> 5 Open the application with its window at its current size and
>   position.
>
> 7 Open the application with a minimized window. The active window
>   remains active.
>
> 10 Open the application with its window in the default state specified
>   by the application.
>
> ---
>
> **Return Value**
>
> **No return value.**
>
> ---
>
> Remarks
>
> This method is equivalent to launching one of the commands associated
>   with a file's shortcut menu. Each command is identified by a verb
>   string. The supported verbs vary from file to file. The most commonly
>   supported verb is "open", which is also usually the default verb.
>   Others might be supported only by certain types of files. For further
>   discussion of Shell verbs, see Launching Applications or Extending
>   Shortcut Menus.
>
> This method is not currently available in Microsoft Visual Basic.
>
> Examples
>
> The following example uses ShellExecute to open Microsoft Notepad.
>   Proper usage is shown for Microsoft JScript and Visual Basic Scripting
>   Edition (VBScript).
>
> ```
> <script language="VBScript">
>     function fnShellExecuteVB()
>         dim objShell
>
>         set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
>
>         objShell.ShellExecute "notepad.exe", "", "", "open", 1
>
>         set objShell = nothing
>     end function
> </script>
> ```

Now all COM calls look like this `HResult = methodcall(param1, param2, ..., paramn, OUTPARAM)`.

VB pretends it `OUTPARAM = methodcall(param1, Param2, ..., paramn)` with `HResult` appearing in the `err.object`.

So errors will still fire, it's just that it doesn't wait to find out.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Instead of quoting the documentation you could have [linked to it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) though. I had read the doc which does not mention a return value although it does say `Shell.ShellExecute` is `As Integer`. Not knowing VBScript I don't know whether that means it returns an integer or not. Anyway, your answer is still acceptable. The answer could be boiled down to "Yes, it's asynchronous. If you want the result you have to wait on err.object".

Comment: Also... how do I tell when ShellExecute is done so I know when err.object will have valid data?

Comment: As I keep saying IT WON'T. Now all com calls look like this HResult = methodcall(param1, param2, ..., paramn, OUTPARAM). VB pretends it OUTPARAM = methodcall(param1, Param2, ..., paramn) with HResult appearing in the err.object. So error will still fire, it's just that it doesn't wait to find out. But your function is finished. So there is NO WAY TO COMMUNICATE IT. Don't use ShellExecxute if you don't like it.