# VBScript's ShellExecute return codes

Tags: vbscript, uac

Is there a possibility to have a return code (a Bool maybe?) to know if the UAC dialog were accepted or rejected? I now do it without checking as follows.

```
Set Shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Shell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & SOME_LOG_PARSING_SCRIPT_FULLPATH_HERE & """ uac", "", "runas"
```

It would be nice for me to know if the user accepted the uac dialog (if any).

Comment: Maybe not quite a duplicate, but this seems highly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27222097/4996248

Comment: I must suffer from PEBKAC because i can't see where his actual answer is. He just pasted a manual section but no answer about the OP's question ... actually.

Comment: maybe it doesn't help, but the accepted answer seemed like it might give you some idea. If not, hope that somebody else can give you a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dozens of times said: *[basically, no, what you're asking isn't possible.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37951243/3439404)* However, there is a workaround which answers the question with *high likelihood* although there is still *non-zero probability of false response*. Here's a draft of such solution, see the script below:

- If elevated already then the answer is 100%: *UAC prompt not required*.
- Otherwise, count *elevated* `wscript.exe` *before* the UAC prompt and *after* it:

  - if counters match then *UAC prompt was **probably** refused*;
  - if counters differ then *UAC prompt was **probably** approved*.

Above method might fail if an *elevated* `wscript.exe` was asynchronously started or finished in the meantime… For instance, from a `RDP` session or from Task Scheduler etc.

```
option explicit
On Error GoTo 0
Dim strResult: strResult = Wscript.ScriptName

Dim objShell, svcCounter, preCounter, postCounter
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

svcCounter  = 0
preCounter  = 0
postCounter = 0

Call TestProcess ( "SVC", svcCounter, "svchost.exe" )
strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & Cstr( svcCounter)

If svcCounter  = 0 Then
    '' elevated already
    strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & "UAC prompt not required"
    objShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe" _
        , """" & "D:\VB_scripts\SO\37911301.vbs" & """ uac" , "", "runas", 1
Else
    preCounter  = 0

    Call TestProcess ( "pre", preCounter, "wscript.exe" )

    ' By default, Windows Vista/7/8's UAC prompt is shown on a _secure desktop_
    ' suspending calling process temporarily:
    objShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe" _
        , """" & "D:\VB_scripts\SO\37911301.vbs" & """ uac" , "", "runas", 1

    Call TestProcess ( "post", postCounter, "wscript.exe" )

    strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & Cstr( preCounter) & vbTab & Cstr( postCounter)
    If preCounter = postCounter Then
        strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & "UAC prompt PROBABLY refused" 
    Else
        strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & "UAC prompt PROBABLY approved"
    End If
End If

Wscript.Echo strResult
Wscript.Quit

Sub TestProcess( byVal sStage, byRef nCounter, byVal strCap)

  strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & sStage 
  Dim strQuery, objWMIService, colItems, objItem, sCaption, sCmdLine
  Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = &h10
  Const wbemFlagForwardOnly       = &h20

  strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Caption = '" & strCap & "'"

  Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & "." & "\ROOT\CIMV2")
  Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery(strQuery _
          , "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)

  For Each objItem in colItems
      sCaption = objItem.Caption
      sCmdLine = objItem.CommandLine
      if VarType( sCmdLine ) = 1 Then nCounter = nCounter + 1  'Null => elevated
      strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & sCaption
      strResult = strResult & vbTab & objItem.ProcessId
      strResult = strResult & vbTab & sCmdLine
      'strResult = strResult & vbTab & VarType( sCmdLine ) & vbTab & TypeName( sCmdLine )
  Next
End Sub
```

Note that all that junk with `strResult` is there merely for debugging purposes. And… I *know* that `TestProcess` call used for test *if elevated already*  is too heavy artillery against a mosquito…

Answer (score 1):

Although the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745.aspx) suggests otherwise `ShellExecute` doesn't actually return anything, because the method runs asynchronously (i.e. returns immediately without waiting for the new process to terminate). Synchronous calls in VBScript can be made with the [`Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky.aspx) and [`Exec`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a.aspx) methods, but those don't allow privilege elevation.

Basically, no, what you're asking isn't possible.